# In focus row in Xceed datagrid doesn't get updated

Tags: xceed, xceed-datagrid

I have a Xceed Datagrid whose `ItemsSource` is `CollectionViewSource` defined in XAML. Whenever grid is updated, only the row which is in focus doesn't show updated values (revert back to original values) but all of other rows are updated. If I directly bound the grid to a Collection in `ViewModel` then everything works fine. The problem is only when, `CollectionViewSource` comes into picture. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try using the `DataGridCollectionViewSource` instead of a `CollectionViewSource`. By using this, you will reap the benefits of the `DataGrid` such as built in filtering, sorting, grouping, etc. An example from their documentation:

```
<Grid xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid">
  <Grid.Resources>      
  <xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs_orders"
                                  Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current},
                                                      Path=Orders}"/>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <xcdg:DataGridControl x:Name="OrdersGrid"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs_orders}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -3):

I got solution...
grid.CurrentItem = null

Comment: Consider using my solution as an alternative. Better to use the right solution instead of a hack